# How do we plug in numbers for things like $x_k$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

In the following example, where you plug in $k=1$ for $x_k$, you get $x$. But If I plugged in $k=2$ would I get $2x$? Also if this is not the case what is an explanation on finding this?

[image]

Comment: No, for $k=1$ you get $x_1$, for $k=2$ you will get $x_2$ and so on.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought. But the solution has $\int^3_02\pi(x+1)(3x-x^2)dx$. I was wondering why there is no $x_1$ and just an $x$?

Comment: If the  $$\Delta x_i$$ are very small, then $$\Delta x_i\approx dx$$

Comment: This is the Riemann sum definition of an integral where $x_k$ denotes the value of the function evaluated at the $k$th partition. When you convert the summation into the equivalent integral there is no need to use subscript notation as the integral is performed without these values being calculated.